# Create excel pivot with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, pivot

I am using below code to create an excel pivot in javascript

```
var xcl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
iUi = xcl.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(2);
xcl.Visible = true;
var newBook = xcl.Workbooks.Add();
var wsSheet = newBook.Worksheets.Add();
var rnStart = wsSheet.Range("A1");
wsSheet.Name = "Results";
var ptCache = newBook.PivotCaches.Add(2, "");
```

but get wrong message for PivotCaches.Add.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that row
    var ptCache = newBook.PivotCaches().Add(2, "");

Now works fine !